# CSS ignored when viewing on an iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, css

This is an issue I've only just come across today and was wondering what could be causing such a strange issue.

I've had a look at a few example websites and they all experience the same issue. I've opened up the Chrome developer tools to check and the CSS relating to these elements appear under "@media all".

Basically when viewing a site on an iPad running iOS 8.1.2 it seems to ignore the CSS for specific elements completely. This is what it looks like on an iPad (bad):

http://i.imgur.com/wd4xnq4.png

Now this is what I see when using Chrome on Windows (CSS loads and is used, the good version...):

http://i.imgur.com/3aMNPXF.png

I've never seen this before and the CSS isn't loaded in with JavaScript with JS disabled so I'm completely stumped. Help please.

**EDIT**

Here is the code. I've double checked and it seems as if a class of .active is added when you click on it to show it is the current selected item.

**EDIT 2**

Here is all the code instead of just the buttons themselves:

```
.product-view .product-collateral{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin:15px 0 0;
}

.product-view .product-collateral #product_tabs ul.r-tabs-nav{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.product-view .product-collateral #product_tabs ul.r-tabs-nav li{
  float: left;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
}

.product-view .product-collateral #product_tabs ul.r-tabs-nav li a{
  padding:10px 15px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #bcbec0;
  color: #fff;
}

.product-view .product-collateral #product_tabs ul.r-tabs-nav li.r-tabs-state-active a{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333333;
}

.product-view .product-collateral #product_tabs .tab{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: Updated the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test it on the iPad? Google chrome also? Are you using browser-specific rules for your CSS? Some elements need to be declared multiple times according to the browser in use.

Comment: I'm using Safari on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue. I wasn't the developer that originally worked on this so it was a head scratcher to begin with.

It turns out the resolution of iPads fell directly in between the mobile view port size and the desktop view port size so so I just need to place the mobile CSS inside a new media view port specifically designed for iPads. I'll post my findings but this should work (hopefully).

**EDIT**

Yep, so it turns out there was a media query that was set to big and fell between the two target sizes and the iPad size was right in the middle.

So essentially it was just a `display: block;` that was outside a media query which meant all the CSS was missed and thus only displayed the text. Solved!